# Simplify $\frac{\sin^2 \alpha - \cos^2 \alpha}{\sin \alpha - \cos \alpha}$.

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to know the most efficient yet simple way to simplify the above expression. Note that I'd like the simplification to be **as elementary as possible,** namely using only:

\begin{align*}
\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha &= 1 \\\\
\frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha} &= \tan \alpha \\\\
\frac{\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha} &= \cot \alpha \\\\
1 + \tan^2 \alpha &= \frac{1}{\cos^2 \alpha} \\\\
1 + \cot^2 \alpha &= \frac{1}{\sin^2 \alpha}.
\end{align*}

If these listed elementary equalities are not enough to simplify, please show me the simplest way to do it, preferably deduced from the basic structure of these trigonometric functions.

Comment: $$(a+b)(a-b)=?$$

Comment: Don't even need to use any trig identities, it is simply a difference of perfect squares.

Answer (score 4):

$${(\sin x - \cos x)(\sin x + \cos x)\over (\sin x - \cos x)}= \sin x + \cos x$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha}=\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha$$